# Python csv not writing to file

Tags: python, file-io, csv

I am trying to write to a .tsv file using python's CSV module, this is my code so far

```
file_name = "test.tsv"
TEMPLATE = "template.tsv"
fil = open(file_name, "w")
# Added suggested change 
template = csv.DictReader(open(TEMPLATE, 'r'), delimiter='\t')
new_file = csv.DictWriter(fil, fieldnames=template.fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
new_file.writeheader()
```

basically `TEMPLATE` is a file that will contain the headers for the file, so i read the headers using `DictReader` and pass the fieldnames to `DictWriter`,  as far as i know the code is fine, the file `test.tsv` is being created but for some reason the headers are not being written.

Any help as to why this is happening is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DictReader's first argument should be a file object (create with `open()`), cf. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

You forgot `open()` for the `TEMPLATE` file.

```
import csv

file_name = "test.tsv"
TEMPLATE = "template.tsv"
fil = open(file_name, "w")

# you forgot this line, which will open the file
template_file = open(TEMPLATE, 'r')

template = csv.DictReader(template_file, delimiter='\t')
new_file = csv.DictWriter(fil, fieldnames=template.fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
new_file.writeheader()
```

Comment: i have made the suggested change, however the file is still empty

Comment: it appears to be working on the server, so ill accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to give DictReader opened file instead of file name:

```
csv.DictReader(open(TEMPLATE, 'r'), delimiter='\t')
```

Same for the writer, but opened for writing.